# Traslating custom string issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1

I am trying to translate the street addresses in my local csv file from my theme. I would like to translate the shipping/billing address from checkout.

For the billing address, this part is working

```
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address","Straatnaam"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 2","Huisnumr"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 3","Busnr"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 4","Toevoeging"
```

for the shipping it doesn't work, only like this part:

```
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address %s","Adres %s"
```

But i would like to have it the same as billing . I don't have inline translations and my cache is constantly cleared. Any idea why this is not working for me ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the translations string in the rewritten template file, from:  `$this->__('Street Address %s',$_i)` into `$this->__('Street Address '.$_i)`